# Unable to register schema in Confluent Schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to register an Avro Schema with Confluent schema registry. Schema registry is throwing this error: {"error_code":422,"message":"Unrecognized field: type"}

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data @Sample.avsc  http://localhost:8081/subjects/sample_app-value/versions
```

Comment: Show the schema